# The latest version of ImageMagick crashed ImageMagick++

Tags: c++

I had this simple piece of code in my program that worked great until the newest update of GraphicsMagick:

```
{
   unsigned char *bitmap = new unsigned char[width*height*3];

   /* code that fills bitmap with the width, height, and depth specifed *\

   Image image(width,height,"BGR",CharPixel,bitmap); \\CODE SEGFAULTS HERE AT CONSTRUCTOR!

   image.write(file);
   delete[] bitmap;
}
```

Is seems that now if I use the Image constructor it will segfault.  Seemingly, now I cannot declare an Image object with the newest version of Magick++?

Comment: What are and what is the value of width, height and CharPixel?

Comment: When you update ImageMagik, did you update ImageMagik++? If you didn't, there's your error

Comment: Make sure the alignment is correct. Even if you're working with 24bit color depth the pixels and/or lines may be aligned differently.

Comment: "CODE SEGFAULTS HERE AT CONSTRUCTOR" -- presumably it actually occurs deeper on the stack than this.  Which memory access really caused the fault?  Was it a write or a read?